# Handle Play/Pause event from TV remote in react native

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, android-tv

I'm developing an app for the Android TV and Apple TV in React Native. When I tried to publish the app on plat store it's give an eligibility issue as below:

> **Play/Pause key event is not respected during playback**
>
> Your media apps that play video or music content must respect the play/pause key during playback. Please refer to our Media Play/Pause documentation and Update the Playback State documentation for details.

Is anyone know how we can get Play/Pause event from remote in React Native?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check the [`react-native-music-control`](https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control#register-to-events) which is a React Native module to control remote controls. It handles those things with listeners but there are some limitations when it comes to support both platforms (android + ios).

Comment: @abielita I checked that it's working with mobile control, not with the TV remote.

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya same problem, if you have been fix this problem please share solution.